# When using True Shapeshifter, does the change trigger Healing Transformation?

Tags: feats, druid, pathfinder-2e

True Shapeshifter (Level 20 Druid feat) says

> ...While under the effect of Wild Shape, you can change into any of the other forms on your Wild Shape list...

I am wondering if this triggers Healing Transformation

> ... If your next action is to cast a non-cantrip polymorph spell that targets only one creature... restores hitpoints...

I am figuring that casting Wild Shape triggers Healing Transformation, because it uses focus, but is True Shapeshifter triggering Wild Shape and thus Healing Transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**  True Shapeshifter adds an additional activity you can perform while under the effects of *wild shape*, but it does not cause you to cast the spell again, nor does it state that it counts as casting any spell.  Healing Transformation's trigger is very specific and has no reason to react to your use of the True Shapeshifter activity.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

**Healing Transformation** seems to be directly referencing the **Cast a Spell** action, rather than a generic use of a Spell's effects

In particular **True Shapeshifter** doesn't call out that you're casting a spell, nor does it have the same limitations as the spell it references **Nature Incarnate**.

It says the following.

> Once per day, you can transform into a kaiju, with the eﬀects of *nature incarnate*; if you have Plant Shape, you can instead transform into a green man.

This seems to suggest that you're doing a different action that uses the **effects** of **Nature Incarnate** rather than allowing you to **cast** it.